# Posting data on website using Mechanize Nokogiri Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I need to post data on a website through a program. 
To achieve this I am using Mechanize Nokogiri and Selenium.
Here's my code :

```
 def aeiexport
        # first Mechanize is submitting the form to identify yourself on the website
         agent = Mechanize.new
        agent.get("https://www.glou.com")
              form_login_AEI = agent.page.forms.first
              form_login_AEI.util_vlogin = "42"
              form_login_AEI.util_vpassword = "666"
              # this is suppose to submit the form I think
              page_compet_list = agent.submit(form_login_AEI, form_login_AEI.buttons.first)
              #to be able to scrap the page you end up on after submitting form
              body = page_compet_list.body
              html_body = Nokogiri::HTML(body)
             #tds give back an array of td
              tds = html_body.css('.L1').xpath("//table/tbody/tr[position()>1]/td")
            # Checking my array of td with some condition
              tds.each do |td|
                link = td.children.first             # Select the first children
                if link.html = "2015 32 92 0076 012"   
                 # Only consider the html part of the link, if matched follow the previous link
                  previous_td   = td.previous
                  previous_url = previous_td.children.first.href
                  #following the link contained in previous_url
                  page_selected_compet = agent.get(previous_url)
                  # to be able to scrap the page I end up on
                  body = page_selected_compet.body
                  html_body = Nokogiri::HTML(body)
                  joueur_access = html_body.search('#tabs0head2 a')
                  # clicking on the link
                  joueur_access.click
                  rechercher_par_numéro_de_licence = html_body.css('.L1').xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[1]")
                  pure_link_rechercher_par_numéro_de_licence = rechercher_par_numéro_de_licence['href']
                  #following pure_link_rechercher_par_numéro_de_licence
                  page_submit_licence = agent.get(pure_link_rechercher_par_numéro_de_licence)

                   body_submit_licence = page_submit_licence.body
                   html_body = Nokogiri::HTML(body_submit_licence)
                    #posting my data in the right field
                    form.field_with(:name => 'lic_cno[0]') == "9511681"
```

1) So far what do you think about this code, Do you think there is an error in there
2) This part is the one I am really not sure about : I have posted my data in the right field but now I need to submit it. The problem is that the button I need to click is like this:

```
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="dispatchAndSubmit(document.JoueurRechercheForm, 'rechercher');" value="Rechercher">
```

it triggers a javascript function onclick. I am triying Selenium to trigger the click event. Then I end up on another page, where I need to click a few more times.. I tried this:

```
  driver.find_element(:value=> 'Rechercher').click
                driver.find_element(:name=> 'sel').click
                driver.find_element(:value=> 'Sélectionner').click
                driver.find_element(:value=> 'Inscrire').click
```

But so far I have not succeeded in posting the data. 
Could you please tell me if selenium will enable me to do what I need to do. If can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

At a glance your code can use less indentation and more white space/empty lines to separate the internal logic of `AEIexport` (which should be changed to `aei_export` since Ruby uses snake case for method names. You can find more recommendations on how to style ruby code [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/)).

Besides the style of your code, an error I found at the beginning of your method is using an undefined variable `page` when defining `form_login_AEI`.

For your second question, I'm not familiar with Selenium; however since it does use a real web browser it can handle JavaScript. [Watir](http://watir.com) is another possible solution.

An alternative would be to view the page source (i.e. in Firebug) and understand what the JavaScript on the page does. Then use Mechanize to follow the link manually.